# Web API 2 Getting ZIP files returned strange symbols

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api2

As I was trying to get a zip file from my one of my dir through API, I always get this random or strange symbols.

```
var path = D:\\Source\\API\\TEST\\XMLPDF\\test.zip;
HttpResponseMessage reponse = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
reponse.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
reponse.Content.Headers.ContentType =
    new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
return reponse;
```

I've used the code above to return the zip file.

[image]

I've added a screenshot from the return body of postman.

Has anyone encountered this kind of issue?

Comment: That looks like a .zip file containing a .pdf.

Comment: yes the zip file is composed of xml and pdf.

Comment: Is it that you need it to set it to download instead of display in the browser? Not sure what you're asking.

Comment: i mean that looks like the code of a pdf inside a zip file, are you saving it as binary and trying to open it?

Comment: the zip file has a xml and ubl inside of it. I need to get the zip through API, do you have any idea why I am getting that strange issue.

Comment: What you're seeing is the ascii representation of the binary zip file. The header looks like it's [PKZip](https://users.cs.jmu.edu/buchhofp/forensics/formats/pkzip.html).

Comment: I'm having an idea now but why Im getting a PKZip since the zip file I created is just a normal one.

Comment: @FritsJ I could be wrong about it being PKZip, it might be another implementation in the same family. Looks to be a zip file, though, which I understand is what you want. I'd try saving the response stream to a file and opening it up.

Comment: `PK` is the [magic string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures) which marks all .zip files. PKZip is the name of the program which creates .zip files. If you're trying to get a .zip file through the API it looks like you have succeeded, but you probably need to make the browser download the file rather than display it.